# change walk mode keys configuration

Tags: 3d-view

I can't find the entries in User Preferences (input tab) to change the keys for navigating in 3D view, using walk navigation mode.

Currently it's bind to WASD keys, and since I have an AZERTY keyboard, it would be nicer to have ZQSD mapping to move the view.

Is it hard coded into Blender's source code ? Or do I miss the entries in User preferences ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I finally found the entries in User preferences.

Into 'Input' tab, then into `3D view` > `View3D Walk Modal`, all keys bindings are listed here.

Oddly, we can not find it using the search tool at the top...